# Android get position of spannable in original html

Tags: android, html, spannable

If I know the position of a certain character in a spannable how to I get the corresponding position in the html? For example if I have the string:

```
<b>example</b>
```

and I know the letter 'p' is at position 4 in the spannable, how do I find out that it is at position 7 in the html?

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html. Use jsoup to extract text from html tag.

Comment: @Raghunandan can you elaborate? I don't see how extracting the text will help, I already know what the text is (in this case the letter 'p') I need to find what position in the HTML this is.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract text from tags and then find the position of the character.

```
    String mystring= "<b>examplep</b>";
    for( int i=0; i<mystring.length(); i++ )
    {
      if( mystring.charAt(i) == 'p' ) 
       {
        System.out.println("index is"+i);//will print 7 and 10 
       }
    }
```

Parsing with jsoup

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(mystring);// can parse html tags uisng jsoup
    Elements elements = doc.select("b");
    String s= elements.text();
    System.out.println("String is"+s);
    for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ) 
    {
    if( s.charAt(i) == 'p' ) 
     {
     System.out.println("index is"+i);
     }
    }
```